# If $f_n^2\to f^2$ uniformly, with $f$ and $fn$ being non-negative, does $f_n\to f$ uniformly?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

I think it is true, and what I am trying to do is, since $f_n^2\to f^2$ uniformly, then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $m\in \Bbb Z$ such that for all $x$, and for all integer $n\geq m$, we have $\left|f_n^2(x) - f^2(x)\right|<\epsilon$. I am not sure if I could split the problem into cases based on the value of $f(x)$ as following, if $f(x) = 0$, then |$f_n^2(x) - 0$| < $\epsilon^2$, which implies |$f_n(x) - 0$| < $\epsilon$, that is |$f_n(x) - f(x)$| < $\epsilon$, and if $f(x) \neq 0$, then let $M = f_n(x) + f(x)$, then we have |$f_n^2(x) - f^2(x)$| < $M\epsilon$, then |$f_n(x) - f(x)$| $=$ $\left|\frac{f_n^2(x) - f^2(x)}{f_n(x) + f(x)}\right| < \frac{M\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon$. I wonder if this approach is correct, is it OK to vary the $\epsilon$ base on the values of $x$ and $f(x)$? Is there any other better ways to prove this statement?

Comment: It is a direct consequence of the fact that the square root is a uniformly continuous function.

Comment: This isn't correct. Why do you have that $|f_n(x)^2-f^2(x)|<M\epsilon$? $M$ could be less than 1.

Comment: @MartinR : How do you make sure that $f_n(x) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: I had assumed that *all* functions are non-negative. Without that assumption, the statement is obviously wrong.

Comment: You could have, say $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}$ and $f_n(x) = sgn(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{n})\sqrt{|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{n}|}$, where $sgn$ is the sign function. (For simplicity of notation, say, these are defined for $x \geq 1$). You have uniform convergence of $f_n^2 = |\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{n}|$ to $f^2 = \frac{1}{x}$. EDIT : Nevermind.

Comment: @MartinR Why is it obviously wrong ?

Comment: $f_n(x) = -1$, $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: @MartinR Yup, I'm an idiot. I was trying to look for edge cases, like, stuff that tends to 0...

Comment: Sorry! My bad! $f_n$ is non-negative needs to be added to the statement.

Comment: @MartinR : I think I had somehow convinced myself that the hypothesis was : $\forall \varepsilon >0\, \forall x \, \exists n \, f_n(x) \geq - \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is no correct. The number $\varepsilon$ remains fixed from the start.

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since the square root function is uniformly continuous, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$(\forall x,y\geqslant0):|x-y|<\delta\implies \left|\sqrt x-\sqrt y\right|<\varepsilon.$$So, take $N\in\Bbb N$ so large that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\forall x\geqslant0):n\geqslant N\implies\left|f_n^{\,2}(x)-f^2(x)\right|<\delta$$and then$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\forall x\geqslant0):n\geqslant N\implies\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|=\left|\sqrt{f_n^{\,2}(x)}-\sqrt{f^2(x)}\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: How do you make sure that $f_n(x) \geq 0$ ?

Comment: @FiMePr It was a mistake, but now the OP has added that assumption to the problem.

Comment: I think your last inequality should read $|\sqrt{f_n^2(x)}-\sqrt{f^2(x)} | < \varepsilon$. Otherwise, it is a nice and clean proof !

Comment: @FiMePr I've edited my anwer. Thank you.